# How to make count increase while user enters correct input on python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to increase the count as the user enters the right inputs. There are items in a list that the input has to match if the items are on the list then I want to increase the count by one and I want to keep asking the user the same question but as he answers I want the input to increase.

```
list = ["Olives", "Bacon"]

while True:
    count = 1
    toppings = input(str(count) + ".")

    if toppings in list:
    count += 1

    else:
        print("Sorry, " + toppings + " is not an available topping")
```

Comment: So basically if they enter Olives or Bacon I want the count to increase.

Comment: It looks like an infinite loop. When do you want it to stop?

Comment: When the user enters done but I know how to do that, I'm just confused on how I can make the count increase when the user enters an input that's in the list. Any idea on how I can do this?

Comment: You set `count=1` inside the while loop, you should define it before such as `count=0`

Comment: Also mind that you seem to miss indentation just after the `if` statement. This might be a typo...